# Calculus Proof Question (Differentiable)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

```
Prove that if f is a differentiable odd function then f ' is an even function.
```

Hello, I don't completely understand what this question means?

What does it mean by f is a differentiable odd function then f (prime) is even function.... aren't both the things the same thing?

If someone could just explain this question to me step by step that would be good. No need to solve it.

THANKS !

Comment: A differentiable function is a function that has a derivative.  The derivative of such a function is denoted by the prime.  So no they are not the same. "Differentiable" is a word applied to $f$ that tells us that $f'$ exists. ("Differentiable" = "able to be differentiated")

Answer (score 5):

A function is *even* if for all $x$ such that it makes sense, $f(-x)= f(x)$. A function is *odd* for $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

So the question is asking:

> Suppose that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$, and show that $f'(-x) = f'(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Setup an equation for an odd function:

$$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

Derive both sides:

$$-f'(-x) = -f'(x) \iff f'(-x) = f'(x)$$

So $f'(x)$ is even.